# why am I getting wrong requestCode?

Tags: android

I have an Activity in which I use `startActivityForResult(intent,634)`. If I using it from activity, requestCode in `onActivityResult()` is Ok. But if I use `startActivityForResult(intent,634)` from my DialogFragment in this Activity, I'm getting another requestCode, something like 66170. So why its happens?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It happens because if you use `startActivityForResult` from the dialog, in `onActivityResult` you get the requestCode of the dialog. Not from your another Activity. And if you want to get right requestCode, you should use `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode)` in DialogFragment.

Comment: Not stupid at all. I ran into the exact same issue. It's very confusing behavior.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when calling StartActivityForResult from a fragment

Comment: It should be added though that the reason for this is that when calling `startActivityForResult` from a fragment android encodes the fragment in the request code so that the activity knows which fragment it comes from. See the source code for more. http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#832